# Serializing two dimensional array using JMS Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a data structure which represents a table, rows and cells. I need to serialize and deserialize it into JSON and XML. How can I configure JMS Serializer to serialize this kind of object,

```
class Test {
    public $data = [
        'row_one' => ['cell-11', 'cell-12'],
        'row_two' => ['cell-21', 'cell-22'],
    ];
}
```

Into this XML:

```
<result>
    <data>
        <row index="row_one">
            <cell>cell-11</cell>
            <cell>cell-12</cell>
        </row>
        <row index="row_two">
            <cell>cell-21</cell>
            <cell>cell-22</cell>
        </row>
    </data>
</result>
```

I already tried to use object which represent a row with `@Inline` annotation, it does not work for deserialisation in JSON, rows are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to (de-)serialize my object using a separate object for each Row.

My mapping looks like:

```
class Table
{
    /**
     * @\JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Inline
     */
    private $rows = [];

    public function __construct(array $rows)
    {
        $this->rows = $rows;
    }
}

class Row
{
    /**
     * @\JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Inline
     */
    private $values = [];

    public function __construct(array $values)
    {
        $this->values = $values;
    }
}
```

Then I serialize my object using JMS Serializer:

```
echo $serializer->serialize(new Table([
    new Row(['cell-11', 'cell-12']),
    new Row(['cell-21', 'cell-22'])
]), 'json');
```

Unfortunately with this approach deserialization does not work due to the bug I tried to fix in here - https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/513